# Why shadow of a view is created as inner

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3

I try to create a standard shadow of the view, which I create as subview for cell.contantView, but shadow apply to other items in view (except the view) if I do not specify .shadowPath, or shadow is created as inner if I do.

```
cell.cellView.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: cell.contentView.bounds.width, height: initialCellHeight)

cell.cellView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
cell.cellView.layer.shadowRadius = 2
cell.cellView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize.zero
cell.cellView.layer.shadowOpacity = 1
cell.cellView.layer.masksToBounds = false
cell.cellView.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: cell.cellView.bounds).cgPath

cell.contentView.addSubview(cell.cellView)
```

Please, help, I have spent all day trying to resolve this problem.

Comment: Why are you adding your cell.cellView as subView of your contentView again?

Comment: have you added other items into that view which you want to have shadow or cell ?

Comment: Shadow with cells is very tricky because you have no control over the rendering order (their z-index).

Comment: 1. Again? I do not. I adding that only once at the end... Maybe I do not understanding something...

2. Yes I have added but I do not want to It have shadow.

3. I try to set zPosition, but it didn't even effect on displaying shadow.

Answer (score 0):

^ you can add and UIView that have all subview of Your cell

^ then add another UIView under this previous one for Shadow only
as  eg. shadowLayer

```
cell.shadowLayer.layer.masksToBounds = false
cell.shadowLayer.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 0)
cell.shadowLayer.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
cell.shadowLayer.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.23
cell.shadowLayer.layer.shadowRadius = 4
```

Comment: It is cell.contantView, isn't it?

Comment: We already have the main view - contantView. I also have deleted all content in cell.cellView (I thought that without setting shadowPath and without view's content I will get normal shadow), but view's shadow disappear at all.